# wix specify licence shows nothing

Tags: wix, installation, rtf, wix3.5

I'm trying to specify the licence for my wix setup project.

I have created a rtf with a few dummy lines in wordpad/notepad/vs tried a few different ways as I read there was an issue with ones created in word but I dont think that should apply here, in any case I also opened it up in notepad++ and verified there is no funky characters hidden in it.

I am specifying the file like so

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Resources\test.rtf" />
```

And the file exists under the project\Resources directory.

When I run the installer all that is shown in the licence area is a blank text box with no scroll bars etc.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Where did you place that <WixVariable> element? The stupid docs are silent on that subject.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Save the license.rtf from WordPad.  See this webpage (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html), specifically this section:

> There is a known issue with the rich
>   text control used to display the text
>   of the license file that can cause the
>   text to appear blank until the user
>   scrolls down in the control. This is
>   typically caused by complex RTF
>   content (such as the RTF generated
>   when saving an RTF file in Microsoft
>   Word). If you run into this behavior
>   in your setup UI, one of the following
>   workarounds will fix it in most cases:
>
> Open your RTF file in WordPad and save
>   it from there in order to remove the
>   complex RTF content from the file.
>   After saving it, rebuild your MSI. Use
>   a dialog set other than the
>   WixUI_Minimal set. This problem
>   typically only occurs when the license
>   agreement screen is the first one
>   displayed during setup, which only
>   happens with the WixUI_Minimal dialog
>   set.

Comment: quite strange even tho i created the original file using new text file and renaming it to rtf and then saving it with wordpad it didnt work, when I started off in wordpad then saved the document it did

Comment: I found an additional trick to make this work - just opening an existing complex RTF file with WordPad and saving it again didn't work. What I did that has consistently worked is to open it with Microsoft Word, Select all (CTRL-A), Copy (CTRL-C), and then in a WordPad window, Paste (CTRL-V). Then Save-As in WordPad. This creates the simplified RTF file that is usable by the RTF control.

Comment: Changing the dialog to something other than WixUI_Minimal, while it may solve this problem, is not always an acceptable work around. Luckily @KevinBrock's resave steps worked for me with WixUI_Minimal.

Comment: WixUI_customization link is broken.

Comment: Link is now fixed, @user3613932.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to @Daniel Powell's decision

1. Open WordPad
2. Write your text
3. Save by default(rtf)
4. Rebuild your msi
5. Profit.

Answer (score 3):

Open trf file in wordpad instead of md-word, It will solve the scroll issue

Answer (score -1):

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="test.rtf" />
```

and include your test.rtf in the Setup project.

Comment: Could you fix your answer to include the **precise** location of where to put that line ?

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The problem is text not showing.