# Why is my license not showing up?

Tags: wix, rtf

In my `<Product>` I have:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="LICENSE.rtf" />
```

`LICENSE.rtf` exists, and is an rtf file (I've tried saving with a few different programs in case it was a problem with one of them).

The file contains text (a whole license!), and the text is sensibly formatted.

Why then, is the License field of my installer blank?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [wix specify licence shows nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380724/wix-specify-licence-shows-nothing)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out you basically *must* generate your rtf with Wordpad, or make a perfect replica. Since mine are generated by scripts, I adjusted my script to insert the Wordpad header to the rtf file, and this fixed it.

Comment: Yes, realize that Windows Installer 1.0 was invented back in the late 1990's targeting Win95/98/NT4/Win2k.  The RichText control is really, really long in the tooth and it's never been updated to preserve backwards compatibility.