# creating a rtf file from a text file using MS DOS commands with wordpad header inserted in the rtf file

Tags: batch-file

I was going through the link [Why is my license not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364935/why-is-my-license-not-showing-up) in which Tom has answered the question that he adjusted the script to add wordpad header to the rtf file. I basically want to know how we can achieve this using MS DOS commands in a bat file

Comment: you really using MS DOS? Or windows command line perchance.

Answer (score 0):

Just open up wordpad, type anything and save the .rtf file. Now open the .rtf file you just created in a plain text viewer like notepad or notepad++. The first couple of lines are the rtf header.

so the batch code to create an rtf file would look like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "myrtf=C:\rtffile.rtf"

>%myrtf% echo {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
>>%myrtf% echo {\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22\par
>>%myrtf% echo this is a test\par
>>%myrtf% echo }
```