# WiX installer: Product End User Agreement shows dummy text

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have an existing setup project. The end user license dialog shows dummy text (Lorum ipsum) instead of the default agreement. I have been trying to resolve the issue but I cannot figure out what to change and how to get the default end user licence agreement?

(I didn't post the codes because it has a lot of company's urls.)

But here a chunk for UI node:

```
<UI Id="MyWixUI_FeatureTree">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

  <DialogRef Id="PlatformServiceDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="IMDatabaseDetailsDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="EmailDatabaseDetailsDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="SMTPSettingsDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="EmailRecipientsDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="ServiceCredentialsDlg"/>

  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[DATA_DIRECTORY]" Order="1">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServiceCredentialsDlg">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

**The licence agreement looks like this :**

[image]

Comment: Based on this link: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/04/15/WiX-3-Tutorial-Custom-EULA-License-and-MSI-localization.aspx, check out `<Control Id="LicenseText" ... >...</Control>`

Comment: Also, from another link http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html, it suggests how to change default placeholder licence text, by using the `<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="bobpl.rtf" />` tag.

Comment: I already used the later one but this displays the blank.

Comment: Then it could mean your file is not being read correctly (due to format or path issues). Try the suggestions from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380750/6741868

Comment: Powell's comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380724/wix-specify-licence-shows-nothing saved my day...

Comment: Please add an answer to your solution, so other people won't look at the comments.

Answer (score 15):

**Answer:**

You have to insert a line of code in between the product tag within Product.wxs file.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="test.rtf" />
```

For **Value**, insert the path of your .rtf file (mine was in root directory so no need to give the full path).

**Note**: Steps of creating your .rtf file:

- Go to the directory where you want to create your .rtf file.
- Type/ copy-paste your licensing text in the **word-pad** and save it with extension .rtf.
- Give the path in the **Value** field.
- rebuild your setup project.
- verify your installation file.

**May not apply to all:** I could see that creating .rtf file using MS Word didn't work for me. It just displayed blank in the license area of the installer.

References: From Powell's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380724/wix-specify-licence-shows-nothing)

Comment: That's one way. Another is in the .wixproj if you are using light.  Another is at the command line passing -d Name=Value into light if you aren't using MSBuild.    Regarding RTF,  Windows Installer's Rich Text controll is really old.  It's best to use Word Pad on the oldest VM you can find if you want to be really safe.  Otherwise be sure to test the rendering on different versions of Windows.

Comment: Not a valid source file