# Wix installer shows dummy text

Tags: windows-10, wix3

I am trying to create a simple wix installer using wixui_minimal and I am having an issue with showing my license text. Instead, when the installer is run it shows a dummy text "Lorem Ipsum" which I understand is a placeholder text.

here is part of  the installer code in product.wxs

```
`     
<!-- Top banner. 493 x 58 -->
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="UIBanner.bmp" />
<!-- Background bitmap on welcome and completion dialogs. 493 x 312 -->
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Dialog.bmp" />
 <!--EULA-->
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtF" Value="license.rtf"/>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />

<Property Id="WIXUI_MINIMAL"  Value="INSTALLFOLDER"/>`
```

I have noticed the build will succeed even if I put gibberish for the "Value" in
WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtF" Value="license.rtf"/> instead of actual license file.

I have read another post here on issue with dummy text but the solutions offered there did not help.

Thank for any help on this.

Comment: I am building on VS2015

Answer (score 0):

This was answered back about 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867565/wix-installer-product-end-user-agreement-shows-dummy-text). I'm guessing [this](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) is the link you're referring to.

Be sure that you're putting the variable description in the Product node.

Have you tried using the -d flag when [building](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html)? You can pass the location of the RTF into the build

Comment: I have seen both links you mention @Doc. But they did not help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in  , the Id="WixUILicenseRtF"  should be Id="WixUILicenseRtf", lowercase 'f' at the end.