# Non-breaking spaces not working in WiX EULA

Tags: unicode, wix, rtf

Even that EULA displayed in WiX is RTF file, and it seems to be fully capable of unicode support, for some reason [non-breaking whitespaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) aren't rendered as such.

[image: There is \u00A0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigation shown that non-breaking spaces are stored in RTF (which is [internally plain text ASCII file](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)) as `\~` *control word*. Though other non-ASCII characters are stored using `\'xx` control word, where x are hexadecimal digits. Simple search-replace of `\~` to `\'a0` did the trick.

Apparently, that's limitation of parsing module in control used to display EULA. Sadly, it's definitely not [the biggest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380724/wix-specify-licence-shows-nothing).

[image]